# Window or class library isn't closing

Tags: c#, wpf

If i close my application with the X Button, something is still open and i have to close it via the stop button on visual studio. 
It only happens when i open a second window which uses a lot of class librarys.

is there any way to determinate which part of the application is still running?

Comment: Do you run any background process?

Comment: yes, two. but i close them both (dispose) the window itself cant close unless both workers arent busy anymore

Answer (score 1):

It isn't enough information for finding a fix for me. But I guess that some of your background processes aren't closed or something similar. You have to check your background processes more deeply.

I recommend you to use **Parallel Tasks** and **Parallel Stacks** windows. You could read there more about them:

- [How to: Use the Parallel Watch Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh418499.aspx)
- [Using the Parallel Stacks Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998398.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Debugging a Parallel Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943.aspx)

I think that this could help find a reason for such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app.xaml and after `StartupUri="..."` add this `ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks but i have already done that and it didn't resolve my problem

Comment: Are you changing your mainwindow anywhere in your code?

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow=yourwindow`. You can try to do this on your main window load event for example...

Comment: ah no i dont really do that. all i set is  `this.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;`on the window i open later

Comment: Well,i'd try to specifically set your `Application.Current.MainWindow=yourmainwindow`,maybe after the second window is closed. If that is set, with the ShutdownMode=OnMainWindowClose it should work

Answer (score -1):

In your MainWindow.Xaml add Close event

```
<Window x:Class="ExertERPDesktop.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Height="Auto" Width="Auto"    x:Name="window" TabIndex="0" Foreground="#FFFF00FF" Closed="OnClose">

and in your code behind

private void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```